# How to iterate through a yaml hash structure in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have a hash mapping in my yaml file as below. How Can I iterate through it in simple ruby script? I would like to store the key in a variable and value in another variable in my ruby program during the iteration.

```
source_and_target_cols_map:
 -
    com_id: community_id
    report_dt: note_date
    sitesection: site_section
    visitor_cnt: visitors
    visit_cnt: visits
    view_cnt: views
    new_visitor_cnt: new_visitors
```

the way i am getting the data from the yaml file is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'yaml'

    config_options = YAML.load_file(file_name)
    @source_and_target_cols_map = config_options['source_and_target_cols_map']
puts @source_and_target_cols_map
```

Comment: that key `'source_table'` is not present in your `YAML`

Comment: Yes I know. its just an example. How do I make it present so that I can iterate through the values of the key value pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your `yaml` file it you should get the below `Hash` from the line `config_options = YAML.load_file(file_name)`

```
config_options = { 'source_and_target_cols_map' =>
 [  { 'com_id' => 'community_id',
    'report_dt' => 'note_date',
    'sitesection' => 'site_section',
    'visitor_cnt' => 'visitors',
    'visit_cnt' => 'visits',
    'view_cnt' => 'views',
    'new_visitor_cnt' => 'new_visitors' }
  ]}
```

Then to iterate through you can take the below approach:

```
config_options['source_and_target_cols_map'][0].each {|k,v| key = k,value = v}
```

Comment: Okay that yaml is not working. i think there is something wrong with my yaml. `couldn't parse YAML at line 8 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)`

Comment: @user2081579 yes the *YAML* you had posted,is not valid. But you should get the *Hash* as I have given to you. Then you can access the inner *Hash* with `each` method.

Answer (score 7):

The YAML.load_file method should return a ruby hash, so you can iterate over it in the same way you would normally, using the each method:

```
require 'yaml'

config_options = YAML.load_file(file_name)
config_options.each do |key, value|
    # do whatever you want with key and value here
end
```